# Как стилизовать маркеры у списка под свои собственные без других символов

Tags: css

В данном случае хотелось бы чтобы был круглый черный маркер 8x8 px и внутри него центральная желтая часть 4х4 px. Все что я находил подразумевало использование какого-либо символа или изображения.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приложите ваши попытки в виде разметки и стилей.

Comment: @UModeL у меня все в виде react и js кода, вряд ли это поможет. Ну а так, самое близкое что у меня получилось, это использовать list-style-image: url('marker.png'); но для это нужно где-то нарисовать этот маркер и я не понял как сжать его до маленьких размеров, в общем явно такой себе вариант

Comment: Ну конкретно желтый кружок с черной обводкой можно прямо в css в виде data uri svg положить

Answer (score 2):

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  background: #fbe202;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Стилизация</li>
  <li>маркеров</li>
  <li>списка</li>
  <li>самым</li>
  <li>обычным</li>
  <li>способом</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо!!! Прям идеально

Comment: @Fureless: как я и написал в ответе - это стандартное решение.

Answer (score 1):

С помощью заранее подготовленного изображения

```
 ul {
    list-style-image: url(my_icon.png);
   }
```

Comment: Только написал, что вариант явно такой себе, но видимо по другому никак? А где его подготовить, не подскажите? Или точнее как сжать его до маленьких размеров, если, допустим, изначальное будет 128х128

Comment: Подготовить изначально в графическом редакторе можно